# Apple Mail in El Capitan

Tags: mac

I have not found a way to get Apple Mail to work in El Captain.  I removed Spam Sieve, MsgFiler, Mail Act-On, and followed other suggestions to no avail.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to explain the problem you are seeing. Does Mail.app not launch? Do you see error messages or crashes? A few more details should help attract helpful answers and suggestions.

Comment: In the absence of specific info on "other suggestions", try this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207245/85275

Comment: Apple Mail does not launch.

Comment: It crashes with and error message when I attempt to launch it.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem solved by closing Mail, deleting all e-mail accounts in System Preferences, reinstalling my iCloud e-mail account from scratch - iCloud Mail then OK -  after which I then added my other e-mail accounts - all now OK.  Hope this helps.